# Does anyone have Clojure examples of how to edit data in JTable/TableModel i

Tags: java, swing, clojure, jtable, tablemodel

My attempt to use JTable and ModelTable in clojure has been successful only to the point of being able to read a file and put the data into suitable rows & columns. My difficulty arises when I want to change some of the data. The Clojure examples I have examined only display cell values. 
 If anyone can direct me to 1 or more Clojure examples of how to use listeners associated with JTable/ModelTable I would be most grateful. The application is very simple and only needs to display data in a table then save any changes or additions to a file.

Comment: It looks like you've got yourself a garden variety NullPointerException. What happens when you try to debug this using the usual methods?

Comment: If you're not sure what I mean, then please look at [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you for the null pointer link. The pointer error is a symptom of my ignorance about how to setup listeners for JTable/ModelTable hence my revised question.

Comment: This should be reopened since the question has been changed. Since you are using Clojure why not use seesaw which makes it a lot easier to use JTables cf https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/wiki/Tables

Comment: I have been trying to use seesaw these past several days despite slow going will get there.